# ListView with Custom Adapter plus Custom XML

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I'm trying to make a listViw using a custom adapter plus custom xml file, but when I launch my app on my device, it crash.

I just want ton display in my listView some articles:

- Title (TextView)
- Content (TextView)
- Date (TextView) I will change to Date after...

Well, here is my Article class:

```
package com.example.articles;

public class Article {

    private String titreArticle;
    private String contenuArticle;
    //private Date dateArticle; 
    private String dateArticle;

    public Article(String titre, String contenu, String date){  

        titreArticle = titre;
        contenuArticle = contenu;
        dateArticle = date;     
    }

    public String getTitreArticle() {
        return titreArticle;
    }

    public void setTitreArticle(String titreArticle) {
        this.titreArticle = titreArticle;
    }

    public String getContenuArticle() {
        return contenuArticle;
    }

    public void setContenuArticle(String contenuArticle) {
        this.contenuArticle = contenuArticle;
    }

    public String getDateArticle() {
        return dateArticle;
    }

    public void setDateArticle(String dateArticle) {
        this.dateArticle = dateArticle;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return this.titreArticle +","+ this.contenuArticle +","+ this.dateArticle;
    }

}
```

Here is my main activity xml file (**activity_main.xml**):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewArticle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom XML file for my articles (**article_items.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp" >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/titreArticle"
         style="@style/titreArticleStyle" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/contenuArticle"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          style="@style/contenuArticleStyle" />

     <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/dateArticle"
          style="@style/dateArticleStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom Adapter:

```
package com.example.articles;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article>{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Article> article;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public ArticleAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Article> article){

        super(activity,textViewResourceId,article);

        try {
            this.article = article;
            this.activity = activity;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return article.size();
    }

    public Article getItem(Article position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView titreArticle;
        public TextView contenuArticle;             
        public TextView dateArticle; 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {

                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_items, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.titreArticle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.titreArticle);
                holder.contenuArticle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contenuArticle);
                holder.dateArticle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.dateArticle);

                vi.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

            holder.titreArticle.setText(article.get(position).getTitreArticle());
            holder.contenuArticle.setText(article.get(position).getContenuArticle());
            holder.dateArticle.setText(article.get(position).getDateArticle());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Finaly, my main activity class:

```
package com.example.articles;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listeArticle = null;
    private ArticleAdapter adapter = null;
    private ArrayList<Article> articleArrayList = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listeArticle = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArticle);
        articleArrayList = new ArrayList<Article>();

        articleArrayList.add(new Article("Title1","Content1","11-09-2013"));

        adapter = new ArticleAdapter(MainActivity.this,0,articleArrayList);

        listeArticle.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I'm a new user on Android, thanks for your help and explanations guys! ;)

EDIT: Logcat

```
09-11 14:44:49.414: D/ddm-heap(223): Got feature list request
09-11 14:44:50.324: I/System.out(223): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-11 14:44:50.365: D/AndroidRuntime(223): Shutting down VM
09-11 14:44:50.374: W/dalvikvm(223): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
09-11 14:44:50.374: E/AndroidRuntime(223): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1276)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1147)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1060)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
09-11 14:44:50.434: E/AndroidRuntime(223):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 14:44:50.495: I/dalvikvm(223): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
09-11 14:44:50.657: I/dalvikvm(223): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-11 14:45:11.764: I/Process(223): Sending signal. PID: 223 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Please post your stack trace/log cat output

Comment: @Lapinou your code is working awesome i have checked this

Comment: Maybe some problem with styles used in XML?

Comment: post your styles please  i tried it to run without any styles

Comment: Yes, there is a error on this file: style="@style/contenuArticleStyle" I check this, thank you for helping me :)

Comment: @Lapinou great u got the problem now enjoy with  it all the best

Comment: @Lapinou i will not suggest to use this  System.out.println(e); use Log.d("","") to print the errors in the log